# gendef and cl - installation

Tags: windows-7, python, gcc

I am trying to wrestle myself through a rather complicated installation of theano on Windows 7, 64-bit, Python 2.7. I have little experience in conducting these installations - and am currently stuck on the following line in the helpfile (on http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html)

> Please do so, and verify that the following programs are found:
>   1.where gcc
>   2.where gendef
>   3.where cl
>   4.where nvcc

I have managed to install gcc - but would love any advice on best place (and easiest manner) to install gendef and cl. I don't have a NVIDIA card - so presume nvcc is not needed. Many thanks in advance; W

(I have found solution later myself - the installation of the winpython package provided the required gendef and cl files)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gendef/

Comment: [mingw -- cl is not recognized as an internal or external command -- my mingw in new and environment is true](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17999129)

Comment: [What is the "Visual Studio configuration file", why is nvcc looking for it, why can't it find it, how to fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21456101)

Comment: Basically you need a copy of Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks David. please allow me to ask some follow-up questions. i have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161690/how-to-tell-scons-to-use-mingw-instead-of-msvc . In order to use tools parameter while creating Environment object - do i go to advanced system properties-  environment variables - and simply create a new one called env? Or am i mistaken here?

Comment: I just installed Visual Studio 2015 - but no change so far. do i need to link it to the path or make other changes? are cl and gendef packaged in Visual Studio - or should i still install gendef seperately?

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with environment variables. Probably something to do with the `SConscript file` file mentioned in the question.

Comment: About the VS question I've no idea. I don't use **any** of this stuff. I was just reading the same install document you were (together with a couple of Googe searches, results linked in comments above.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://rosinality.ncity.net/doku.php?id=python:installing_theano) is a much easier set of instructions
It's in both Korean and English

Comment: Just a link to an answer somewhere else is more appropriate as a comment, which requires a little more rep.  Answers should be self contained.  Links break, in which case your answer would have no value.  Include the essential information within your answer (in English), and use the link for attribution and reference.  Thanks.